An old Hindi movie about an artist making villain confess about murder of his girlfriend
This is an old Hindi movie that I'm looking for a long time. And here are the details.
When did I watch it
I watched this movie on TV in 1999.
Possible release year
It was B&W movie and possibly released between 1950-1965.
Plot details
The lead actor of the movie works at a kind of Estate firm and does drawing in spare time. His boss was ruthless and also was villain of this movie. Hero falls in love with a tribal girl after listening her song. He goes out of the town and when he returns, he comes to know that his girlfriend was picked and murdered by his boss. So, he confronts him but gets beaten by his boss's goons.
Later, he meets with a girl who almost looks like his girlfriend. So, he plans to make his boss confess about the murder. Due to fear stormed after seeing that girl, his boss confesses the truth and police waiting outside arrests him.
Hero learns that it was the ghost of his girlfriend who made his boss confess the truth, so he chases her, but dies after falling from terrace.
Any ideas which movie is it?

Sound quite similar to Madhumati only the addition of rebirth in the mix. All the details matched with Wikipedia summary.

While driving his car on a rainy night, Anand's car breaks down, and he goes to seek shelter in a nearby house. He is let into the house by the servant, and he is permitted to stay until the rains stop be able to get his car fixed. It is here that he will find out about his previous birth, his true love, Madhumati, their ill-fated, star-crossed and tragic romance, and how events in his previous birth are going to effect him in this life-time. IMDb

It also sound quite similar to Om Shanti Om which is also based on Madhumati like many other such films.

Yes. It is the movie I was looking for. I wanted to watch it again, but did not know the title. Thanks Ankit :)

@AJ Never seen this film myself but I felt that this might inspired Om Shanti Om and I was right.

has that awesome song - Daya re daya re chad gayo papi bichua -https://youtu.be/FJNZALQYO48
